# Are all algebras Igusa-Todorov?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra

A finite dimensional algebra A is called (n-)Igusa-Todorov in case there exists a module V such that for any module M there is an exact sequence:
$0 \rightarrow V_2 \rightarrow V_1 \rightarrow \Omega^{n}(M) \oplus P \rightarrow 0$, where $P$ is projective and $V_i \in \mathrm{add}(V)$.
See [this 2009 paper by Jiaqun Wei (ScienceDirect link)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870809002187).

In the same paper there is the problem, wheter any algebra is Igusa-Todorov. What is the status of this problem? How about selfinjective $A$? (Then the $n$ does not matter since $\Omega$ is an equivalence. )

The big motivation behind this concept is that if all algebras were Igusa-Todorov, the famous finitistic dimension conjecture would be true. I personally think that not all algebras are Igusa-Todorov and I see no reason why selfinjective algebras should be Igusa-Todorov in general.

Edit: I saw that a selfinjective algebra not being Igusa-Todorov was also noted here: https://teresaconde.xyz/files/thesis.pdf on page 96 (thesis memoir by Teresa Conde, Oxford).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $A$ is self-injective, then I think that $A$ being Igusa-Todorov implies that the dimension (in the sense of Rouquier) of the stable module category $\textrm{stmod-}A$ is at most $1$.

In "Dimensions of triangulated categories", J. K-theory 1 (2008), no.2, 193-256 ([link to arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0310134)), Rouquier defines the dimension of a triangulated category $\mathcal{T}$ as follows:

Given a subcategory $\mathcal{I}$, $\langle\mathcal{I}\rangle$ is the full subcategory containing all direct summands of finite direct sums of shifts of objects of $\mathcal{I}$, and inductively $\langle\mathcal{I}\rangle_1=\langle\mathcal{I}\rangle$ and $\langle\mathcal{I}\rangle_{n+1}=\langle\langle\mathcal{I}\rangle_n\ast\langle\mathcal{I}\rangle\rangle$, where $\langle\mathcal{I}\rangle_n\ast\langle\mathcal{I}\rangle$ is the full subcategory consisting of objects $M$ such that there is a distinguished triangle
$$M_1\to M\to M_2\to\Sigma M_1$$
with $M_1$ in $\langle \mathcal{I}\rangle_n$ and $M_2$ in $\langle\mathcal{I}\rangle$. Then the dimension of $\mathcal{T}$ is defined to be the smallest $d$ such that there is some object $V$ with $\mathcal{T}=\langle V\rangle_{d+1}$.

So if $A$ is an Igusa-Todorov self-injective algebra, then for every module $M$ there is a distinguished triangle
$$V_1\to M\to \Sigma V_2\to \Sigma V_1$$
in $\textrm{stmod-}A$, so $\textrm{stmod-}A=\langle V\rangle_2$, and so the dimension of $\textrm{stmod-}A$ is at most $1$.

So, for example, if $A$ is the exterior algebra of a $3$-dimensional vector space (for which Rouquier proves in Section 8.2 of the same paper that the dimension of $\textrm{stmod-}A$ is $2$), then $A$ can't be Igusa-Todorov.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, not sure without references. Of course selfinjective algebras are not the most interesting since the finitistic dimension conjecture is trivial for them anyway. One idea for non-selfinjective algebras is to look at the stable category of gorenstein projectives then, since gorenstein projective modules can be written as arbitrary syzygies. So another question would be if one can extent your idea to the nonselfinjective case (in case your idea works).

Comment: Maybe like that: Let A be a selfinjective algebra that is not igusa-todorov, and let $M$ be a module of mod-A with $\tau(M) =M$, and $N=A \oplus M$. Then $B=End_A(N)$ is a Gorenstein algebra with the stable category of gorenstein projective modules equal to the stable category of mod-A, so maybe B is also not igusa-todorov.

Comment: Similarly, if A is not self-injective, I believe being n-Igusa-Todorov implies the dimension of the "stable derived category" $D^b(\mbox{mod}-A)/K^b(\mbox{proj}-A)$ is at most 1.  The paper https://arxiv.org/abs/0802.0952 gives some lower bounds for this dimension in terms of the complexity of $A/\mbox{rad}\ A$.  Unfortunately, at the moment, I don't have a specific non-selfinjective example where this dimension is larger than one.