# Gorenstein algebras that are Igusa-Todorov

Tags: rt.representation-theory

I asked here:
[Are all algebras igusa-todorov?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/251312/are-all-algebras-igusa-todorov)
wheter all algebras are Igusa-Todorov.
There was given a counterexample using a certain selfinjective algebra. Since I made the answer green there I post a related question here as a new question.
Given a finite dimensional Gorenstein algebra $A$, the substitute for the stable category is the stable category of Gorenstein-projective modules, which is also equivalent to the singularity category $D^{b}(mod-A)/K^{b}(mod-A)$.
It noted in the previous question as a comment, that being Igusa-Todorov for a Gorenstein algebra $A$ might imply that the singularity category of $A$ has dimension at most 1.
Is this true? If yes one can construct an example of a non Igusa-Todorov algebra that is Gorenstein but not selfinjective as follows:
Take for $B$ a selfinjective algebra of stable dimension at least two (for example the exterior algebra of a vector space with dimension at least three) and take a $B$-module $M$ with $\tau(M) \cong M$. Then the algebra $A:=End_B(B \oplus M)$ will be a Gorenstein algebra with singularity category isomorphic to the stable category of the selfinjective algebra $B$.

Thus there are two questions:

1. Does being Igusa-Todorov imply that the singulairty category has dimension at most one (at least for Gorenstein algebras?)
2. What is an example of a module $M$ with $M \cong \tau(M)$ for a selfinjective algebra $B$ with stable dimension at least two?
   Idea: Take an algebra A with an indecomposable module M of projective dimension one, then the module M over the trivial extension of A has $\tau(M)=M$. Now one just has to find such A with the trivial extension having representation dimension at least 4.
   Here is a wild guess how to obtain such A: Take C the exterior algebra with representation dimension 4, and A=End_C(N), where N is an Auslander generator. Does this work?

Comment: For the second question you could just take the simple module for an exterior algebra on one generator and induce to the exterior algebra on several generators.